# 'Main': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Tags: c#

I am getting error

> 'Main': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type while
>   executing this code.

This code is generated from a project migrated from VB6 to CSharp. Also, please let me know best way for code migration from VB6toCS

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Main : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            vb6Globals.Main = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Main());
        }

        private void Command1_Click(System.Object _sender, System.EventArgs _e1) 
        {
            this.Close();
            vb6Globals.Form1.Show(null);
        }

        private void Command3_Click(System.Object _sender, System.EventArgs _e1) 
        {
            this.Close();
            vb6Globals.Database.Show(null);
        }

        private void Form_Unload(int Cancel) 
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might just be a typo, but isn't that an extra closing brace at the end?

Comment: @Kevin One is for the class, the other is for the namespace

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it helps if your indent is correct.

Comment: No.. its not a typo

Comment: You  have a method called `Main` inside of a class called `Main` I suggest you rename the class to something else, like `Program`.

Answer (score 4):

You `static void Main()` method conflicts with the `Main` class name.

I would suggest to move the `Main` method to a separate class in a file named `Program.cs` (which is the standard).

Something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new MainForm()); // use Form here, just to be clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.

rename this to something else or rename the class.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Main());
}
```

Comment: I love when people leave negative statements and then delete them when the flood of same answer come pouring in [smh]

Comment: Still not working.. error Could not find 'Project1.Main' specified for Main method coming

Comment: @Paul Swetz I was going to reply to his comment, but he deleted it too fast.  Couldn't come up with a good comeback quick enough :(

Comment: Assuming Visual Studio -> Right click the project select properties then in the Application tab set the dropdown Startup Object to the class that has the real Main method to start the app (normally Program), looks like its set to "Project1" for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In a standard Windows Forms project, Program.cs looks just like your static main method.  Here is an exert from a new project called "Test" I just made:

```
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

This is just simply telling it what to run when your application starts.

That code shouldn't be anywhere except inside program.cs.  It looks like your code is currently inside your Main class, which is why you are having issues.